# Getting a list of frequencies and amplitude for each sample in a wav file

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft

This is my first question here. I am looking to make an audio analyzer, which goes through each individual sample of a sound file and compares frequencies. What I am trying to achieve is getting an array with all of the frequencies and amplitudes in this format:

`sound_data = [[0, 0, 1, 0.5 ...], [1, 0.5 ...]]`

Where `sound_data[0][0]` is the first sample at 0 Hz with an amplitude of 0. Or `sound_data[1][1]` is the second sample at 1 Hz with an amplitude of 0.5 all the way up to 20,000 Hz.

This means that for a 10 second long sound with a sample rate of 44,100, `len(sound_data)` would be `441,000`. Or, `len(sound_data[0])` would be 20,000.

I have tried fft with scipy and numpy, and mildly understand that an fft signal is a voltage which is meant to represent a frequency and amplitude, however I cannot figure out how to sort the data into the above mentioned format.

Librosa and aubio also sound like some possible options; I have not experimented with these much.

I'd like to analyse both stereo and mono tracks.

Thank you for any help

Comment: its best to ask questions which focus on a single nugget of information ... here you are conflating way too many ...  I suggest you get familiar making a FFT call by feeding in a known sine curve at a known frequency then try to make sense of the output of that FFT call ...  that alone is 10 days worth of research ... achieve that before attempting to get the data format aligned to your needs

Comment: I'll work on that. Would you recommend learning to use scipy or numpy first?

Comment: I code using golang however in python numpy as the fft functions ... take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592545/plotting-fourier-transform-of-a-sinusoid-in-python    copy into a new empty python source file the code from the question of the link then at the bottom of that just before the   `plt.show()`   command  paste in the entire  fft code in the answer    ....  this will interactively prompt you for the freq and num cycles then plot results ... have fun